# unpacking array extents at compile time (C++11/14)

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I need to "pack" and "unpack" the dimensions of a multidimensional C-style array at compile time. By "pack," I mean given a type which represents an array's dimensions such as

`template<typename T, size_t N2, size_t N3>
struct SomeType<T,0,0,N2,N3> { ... };`

that I can extract a type `T**[N2][N3]` and perform the converse operation
so that given a type `T**[N2][N3]`, I can populate an `std::index_sequence` with parameters `<0,0,N2,N3>`

I've been able to perform the "pack" operation with the code:

```
/*   pack_array_type<T,N0>     is  T[N0]
 *   pack_array_type<T,0>      is  T*
 *   pack_array_type<T,N0,N1>  is  T[N0][N1]
 *   pack_array_type<T,0,N1>   is  T*[N1]
 *   pack_array_type<T,0,0>    is  T**
 *   etc                                  */

using namespace std;

template<typename,typename> struct pack_array_type_impl;

template<typename T, size_t N0, size_t...Ns>   
struct pack_array_type_impl<T,index_sequence<N0,Ns...>> {
  using type = typename 
  pack_array_type_impl<T[N0],index_sequence<Ns...>>::type;
};

template<typename T, size_t...Ns>
struct pack_array_type_impl<T,index_sequence<0,Ns...>> {
  using type = typename 
  pack_array_type_impl<T*,index_sequence<Ns...>>::type;
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct pack_array_type_impl<T,index_sequence<N>> { using type = T[N];};

template<typename T>
struct pack_array_type_impl<T,index_sequence<0>> { using type = T*; };

template<typename T, size_t...N>
using pack_array_type = typename 
pack_array_type_impl<T,index_sequence<N...>>::type;
```

My attempt at the inverse operation to "unpack" the dimensions is

```
template<typename, typename> struct unpacked_array_type_impl;

template<typename T, size_t...I>
struct unpacked_array_type_impl<T,index_sequence<I...>> {
  using index_type = index_sequence<extent<T[I]>::value...>;
};

template<typename T>
struct unpacked_array_type {
  using value_type = decay_t<T>;

  // EDIT: Need condition here to prevent infinite recursion
  using index_type =
  typename unpacked_array_type_impl<T,make_index_sequence<rank<T>::value>>::index_type;
}

// Print indices for testing
template<size_t...N>
void print_sequence( const index_sequence<N...>& seq, ostream& os ) {
  using expand_type = int[];
  os << "[";
  (void) expand_type
  { 0, ((void)(os << integral_constant<size_t,N>() << " ") , 0) ... };
  os << "]\n";
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {

  typename unpacked_array_type<double**[3][4][5]>::index_type x;
  // print_sequence(x,cout); // Desired output = [0 0 3 4 5 ]

  return 0;
}
```

`
Compiling with clang 5.0.1, gives the error

> ```
> main.cpp:54:12: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
>   'unpacked_array_type_impl<double **[3][4][5], details::make_index_sequence<3> >'
>   typename unpacked_array_type_impl<T,make_index_sequence<rank<T>::value>>::type;
>            ^
> main.cpp:68:12: note: in instantiation of template class 'unpacked_array_type<double**[3][4][5]>' requested here
>   typename unpacked_array_type<double**[3][4][5]>::type x;
>            ^
> main.cpp:43:37: note: template is declared here
> template<typename, typename> struct unpacked_array_type_impl;
>                                     ^`
> ```

Is it possible to extract these dimensions?

Note: I am using my own implementation of some C++14 features such as `std::index_sequence` in C++11.

EDIT: Added code https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6776152e348c2c57
This builds, but outputs [3 4 5 ] instead of [0 0 3 4 5 ]

Comment: Is this the exact code? `unpacked_array_type` doesn't have a `type` member?

Comment: Good eye. Also `unpacked_array_type` doesn't have a type. Both instances should have `::index_type` instead. Interestingly, changing this does not affect the compiler output.

Comment: "changing this does not affect the compiler output." - because you use `std::extend` in the wrong way; see my answer for the correct way.

Comment: @GregvonWinckel Really? Because it compiles for me after changing both `index_type`s to `type` and adding the missing template header for `print_sequence`... so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @Barry, I apparently still needed to use `extent<T,I>` instead of `extent<T[I]>`

Comment: So, instead of just adding a link somewhere with code - please just edit the whole question to be the actual code that you are asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some errors in your code.

(1) use ever `type` or `index_type` but not ask for `type`

```
// .......................................................................vvvv
typename unpacked_array_type_impl<T,make_index_sequence<rank<T>::value>>::type;
```

when the class define `index_type`

```
template<typename T, size_t...I>
struct unpacked_array_type_impl<T,index_sequence<I...>> {
  using index_type = index_sequence<extent<T[I]>::value...>;
}; // ..^^^^^^^^^^
```

Same problem for `unpacked_array_sequence` that define a `index_type` when in `main()` you ask for `type`

(2) use `std::extent<T, I>::value...`, not `extent<T[I]>::value...`.

Also observe that with `extent<T[I]>::value ...` you define `T[0]` (when `I` is zero) that isn't acceptable in standard C++.

(3) add `template <std::size_t ... N>` before

```
 void print_sequence( const index_sequence<N...>& seq, ostream& os ) {
```

Correcting this errors you should get the output

```
[3 4 5 ]
```

that isn't exactly what you asked but is an improvement.

To get

```
 [0 0 3 4 5 ]
```

I propose to rewrite `unpacked_array_type_impl` as follows

```
template <typename, typename IS = std::index_sequence<>>
struct unpacked_array_type_impl
 { using type = IS; };

template <typename T, std::size_t ... I>
struct unpacked_array_type_impl<T*, std::index_sequence<I...>>
   : public unpacked_array_type_impl<T, std::index_sequence<0u, I...>>
 { };

template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t ... I>
struct unpacked_array_type_impl<T[N], std::index_sequence<I...>>
   : public unpacked_array_type_impl<T, std::index_sequence<I..., N>>
 { };
```

and use it as follows

```
template<typename T>
struct unpacked_array_type
 { using type = typename unpacked_array_type_impl<T>::type; };
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename, typename IS = std::index_sequence<>>
struct unpacked_array_type_impl
 { using type = IS; };

template <typename T, std::size_t ... I>
struct unpacked_array_type_impl<T*, std::index_sequence<I...>>
   : public unpacked_array_type_impl<T, std::index_sequence<0u, I...>>
 { };

template <typename T, std::size_t N, std::size_t ... I>
struct unpacked_array_type_impl<T[N], std::index_sequence<I...>>
   : public unpacked_array_type_impl<T, std::index_sequence<I..., N>>
 { };

template<typename T>
struct unpacked_array_type
 { using type = typename unpacked_array_type_impl<T>::type; };

// Print indices for testing
template <std::size_t ... N>
void print_sequence (std::index_sequence<N...> const & seq,
                     std::ostream & os)
 {
   using expand_type = int[];
   os << "[";
   (void) expand_type { 0, ((void)(os << N << " ") , 0) ... };
   os << "]\n";
 }

int main ()
 {
   typename unpacked_array_type<double**[3][4][5]>::type x;
   print_sequence(x, std::cout); // Desired output = [0 0 3 4 5 ]
 }
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I think the `extent<T,I>` was the thing that was really keeping me from sorting this out.

Comment: @GregvonWinckel - answer improved to show how to get `[0, 0, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: @GregvonWinckel - answer improved again: added a default type for the second template argument for `unpacked_array_type_impl` so simplified call for it in `unpacked_array_type` (mainly an aesthetically improvement)

Comment: @GregvonWinckel - another point: you don't need `std::integral_constant` in `print_sequence()`; you can simply write `(void) expand_type { 0, ((void)(os << N << " ") , 0) ... };`